# Как преобразовать json в объект

Tags: android, json

Есть файл с расширением json. 
В гугле нашел такой способ конвертирования:

```
 String jsonText = "{\"name\":\"Мурзик\",\"color\":-16777216,\"age\":9}";

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
Cat murzik = gson.fromJson(jsonText, Cat.class);
Log.i("GSON", "Имя: " + murzik.name + "\nВозраст: " + murzik.age);
```

jsonText прописан в классе. Не пойму как получить данные из другого файла, который хранится в assets

Comment: А где находится assets?

Comment: На самом деле ваш вопрос не про Json и объекты, но про чтение файлов из `assets` в строку. Смотрите решение в моём ответе)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот метод на котлине, который читает файл из `assets` в строку по его имени:

```
fun readFromAssets(context: Context, filename: String): String {
    val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(context.assets.open(filename), "UTF-8"))

    // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    var line: String? = reader.readLine()
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line) // process line
        line = reader.readLine()
    }
    reader.close()
    return sb.toString()
}
```